# Android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: java, android

После переименования пакета перестал работать R файл.
На строчке Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.app_name2) вылетает исключение. Причем я так понял setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_foreground) - иконку находит.

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this, ANDROID_CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_foreground)
                    .setContentTitle(Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setContentText("Идет передача координат")
                    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
```

android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f0d0029
Переименовывал через refactor, в настройках gradle изменил applicationId, в манифесте изменил имя пакета. Clean Project пробовал - не помогает.

Comment: C `Resources.getSystem()` можно получить только системные ресурсы, а вы пытаетесь получить ресурсы приложения

Comment: До переименования пакетов все работало. заменил на getString(R.string.app_name) и все заработало. В чем отличие?